# What is a good way of including question examples in a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I'm looking for a good way of including question examples in a sentence.

For example:

Unlike traditional studies which have focused on financial solvency, e.g., "Can the library afford to pay its librarians and buy new books?", these studies will focus on how well allocated money is being used, "e.g. Does it make sense that a library is spending 20% of its income on parking?".

Any suggestions on changes to punctuation, or other ways of writing this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

Unlike traditional studies which have focused on financial solvency (e.g., Can the library afford to pay its librarians and buy new books?), these studies will focus on how well allocated money is being used (e.g. Does it make sense that a library is spending 20% of its income on parking?).

Unlike traditional studies which have focused on financial solvency--e.g., Can the library afford to pay its librarians and buy new books?--these studies will focus on how well allocated money is being used--e.g. Does it make sense that a library is spending 20% of its income on parking?

I prefer the first as it clearly shows that these are just examples and it improves readability. The second emphasizes the examples, which is less to my liking.

By the way, in your example, there should be no period at the end. See CMOS 6.7 for clarification.